# HTML table search getting last row field content after search field has no value

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table with a search field to filter the result by Name. And another field to show the Country tha correspond to the person.

Everything works fine, but when I remove the input from the search field the Country Field gets the country from last row. What I want is that, whenever the search field is empty, the country field should be empty, too.

this is the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("Res").value = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].textContent; //traer nombre del pais indice 1
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<input type="text" id="Res" placeholder="Country" title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a check for the `filter` value, if it's empty, set the `coutry` field to empty "

```
  if(!filter)
    document.getElementById("Res").value = "";
```

```js
function myFunction() {

  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;

  input = document.getElementById("myInput");

  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  table = document.getElementById("myTable");

  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;

      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("Res").value = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].textContent; 
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
        
      }
    }    
  }
  
  if(!filter)
    document.getElementById("Res").value = "";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <h2>My Customers</h2>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

  <input type="text" id="Res" placeholder="Country" title="Type in a name">

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>North/South</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paris specialites</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
  </table>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan i see your answer is more detailed but not sure if it's what the OP wants, he stated that *Everything works fine* and the problem is *whenever the search field is empty, the country field should be empty, too.* and that's what i tried to achieve in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It took some work, but you likely want to look at this

- introduces eventlisteners
- creates a list of countries in the result
- more elegant selections of cells using querySelectorAll and :first-child to only select relevant cells.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", function() { // any input

    var filter = this.value.toUpperCase(),
      td = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr td:first-child"); // first cells

    var countries = [];
    document.getElementById("Res").value = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) { // looping over first cells only

      var txtValue = td[i].textContent || td[i].innerText, // actually textContent is well supported
        found = txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1;

      if (found) countries.push(td[i].nextElementSibling.textContent)

      td[i].closest("tr").style.display = found ? "" : "none"; // show or hide the row
      if (filter) document.getElementById("Res").value = countries.join(", "); 
    }
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<input type="text" id="Res" placeholder="Country" title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```